# PHP: image corrupted if I force the download

Tags: php, image, corruption, corrupt

I've a strange behavior with a simple PHP code. When I try to force the download or print out the image using the correct content-type, the output file is corrupted.

Seems that the webserver (apache) adds two bytes (**0x20 and 0x0A**) at the begin of the file.

This is the code:

```
$file = "image.png";
$image = file_get_contents($file);

// Test
file_put_contents("test.png", $image);

// Download
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));

echo $image;
```

**I use the same code on other websites hosted on the same server without problems.**

The problem is only on download only because test.png works properly. The MD5 checksum of text.png and the original image are equals.

This is the hex code of test.png.

[image]

And this is the hex code of the corrupted file after download:

[image]

As you can see, there are 2 extra bytes at the begin. If I remove them, the file returns to work properly.

I attach the screen of Wireshark (as you can see is not a browser issue):

[image]

How can I fix it?

The server is Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP-5.6 (yes I done the downgrade from 7.0 to 5.6 for compatibility issues with roundcube)

**UPDATE 1:** I'm trying to find if somewhere in the file there is a space + newline

**UPDATE 2:**

First of all: thanks.

The code is part of a Wordpress plugin and the download is called using the AJAX system. I wrote a simple plugin test:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Plugin URI: http://www.google.com
Description: Test
Author: Anon
Version: 4.0
*/
function downlod_test() {
echo "test";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=prova.html');
die();   
}
function iopman_shared_download_doc_ajax() {
downlod_test();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_frontend_download_doc', 'iopman_shared_download_doc_ajax');

//downlod_test();
?>
```

If I call downlod_test with /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=frontend_download_doc it adds the 2 extra bytes. If I call it directly (by removing the comments), it works.

So the problem now is: how to strip out these bytes that wordpress adds?

Comment: x20 is a space and x0A is a newline (aka `\n`). Maybe this helps you figure out where it's coming from. The code you showed should not produce them.

Comment: How to strip them? Find them with get_included_files(), debug_print_backtrace() and then load the file in your editor and remove them.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = "image.png";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
ob_get_clean();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Ali Khanusiya, what does your header code do? What was the problem, and how does it fix it?

Comment: @alexis This answer basically suggests using `ob_get_clean();` to ignore bogus whitespace but he's clearly [missing a bit](https://3v4l.org/Ba5fJ). You can't empty the output buffer if you don't start an output buffer before–and doing so would be quite more complicate than just fixing the issue.

Comment: For some reason, the key here is simply the __ob_get_clean();__. My script which initially used __flush();__ decided to just stop working. It added two extra line-breaks which I could not trace their source. I don't know of any side-effects but at least it works for now pending more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

To help you find that unwanted whitespace you can track loaded files with [get_included_files()](http://php.net/get_included_files). Additionally, a [backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) could also shred some light on what your script does.

In many cases, it'll come from closing PHP tags at the end of the file. Since they're optional it's recommended to just not use them.

Once you locate the file where that white space is, you only need to load in your favourite text editor and remove them (you might need to enable your editor's *Show hidden chars* feature).

P.S. I understand that's probably simplified code to illustrate the issue but you may want to give [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile) a try.